# How to enable/disable services with upstart 0.6.7?

Tags: upstart, services

I need to disable a service in RHEL, before upgrading it. 
Stopping it does not do the trick, because it uses the `respawn` stanza , which causes it to start immediately after I stop it.
The method in https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services namely using `.override` files is not supported in the version of upstart I have (0.6.7 and I cannot upgrade).

I thought of commenting out the `respawn` stanza before stopping the service, and removing the comment after the upgrade is complete.
Is there any other/better idea?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround until upstart is upgraded to 1.3 where the `.override` files are supported, it is possible to comment out the `respawn` stanza.
It can also be automated, .e.g. as part of an rpm script, using the following `sed` commands:

```
# to disable:
sed -i -e 's/^respawn/#respawn/' /etc/init/my_svc.conf

# to enable:
sed -i -e 's/#respawn/respawn/' /etc/init/my_svc.conf
```